# How do I pass arguments to lzip through tar?

Tags: tar, compression

I want to run `tar --lzip -cvf file1.txt file2.txt`. But lzip's help page states that by default it does not run at its fullest compression power (the option for which is `-9`, while the default is `-6`). I could run `tar` first to concatenate the files and then run `lzip -9` on the resulting tar, but is it possible to do so in one command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `tar`'s `-I` option specifying the "compression program":

```
tar -cvf archive.lz -I 'lzip -9' file1.txt file2.txt
```

Or you can pipe `tar`'s output through `lzip`:

```
tar -cvf - file1.txt file2.txt | lzip -9 > archive.lz
```

Both options are described in the [GNU tar manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/gzip.html) (search for the first `-I`).

Comment: Warning: The `-I` option in tar is used to give a list of files to process. If your local `tar` implementation does something else, this is a non-standard behavior.